# Using React.Components with apollo-client and TypeScript

Tags: typescript, react-apollo, apollo-client

I'm trying to build a simple React component using `apollo-client` and TypeScript.

This component just queries for the list of articles and displays them. Code is as follows:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import graphql from "react-apollo/graphql";
import { ARTICLES_FEED } from "../schemas/queries";
import { Article, ArticlesFeedResponse } from "../schemas/results";
import { ChildProps } from "react-apollo/types";

const AppQL = graphql<ArticlesFeedResponse, {}>(ARTICLES_FEED);

class App extends React.Component<ChildProps<{}, ArticlesFeedResponse>, {}> {
    render() {
        const { loading, feed, error } = this.props.data;

        if (loading) return <div>loading</div>;
        if (error) return <div>{ error }</div>;
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <h1>It works!</h1>
                {this.props.data && feed.map( (article:Article) => (
                    <div>{article.shortText}</div>
                ))}
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}

export default AppQL(App);
```

schemas/results:

```
export interface Article {
    id: string,
    shortText: string,
    publicationDate: string
}

export type ArticlesFeedResponse = {
  feed: Article[];
}
```

schemas/queries:

```
import gql from 'graphql-tag'

export const ARTICLES_FEED = gql`
    query ArticlesFeed {
        feed {
            id
            shortText
            publicationDate
        }
    }
`;
```

Nonetheless, signatures match, but i still get an error:

`Type '(QueryProps<OperationVariables> & Partial<ArticlesFeedResponse>) | undefined' has no property 'loading' and no string index signature.`

I don't get what's happening - types imported are:

ChildProps:

```
export declare type ChildProps<P, R> = P & {
    data?: QueryProps & Partial<R>;
    mutate?: MutationFunc<R>;
};
```

QueryProps:

```
export interface QueryProps<TVariables = OperationVariables> {
    error?: ApolloError;
    networkStatus: number;
    loading: boolean;
    variables: TVariables;
    fetchMore: (fetchMoreOptions: FetchMoreQueryOptions & FetchMoreOptions) => Promise<ApolloQueryResult<any>>;
    refetch: (variables?: TVariables) => Promise<ApolloQueryResult<any>>;
    startPolling: (pollInterval: number) => void;
    stopPolling: () => void;
    subscribeToMore: (options: SubscribeToMoreOptions) => () => void;
    updateQuery: (mapFn: (previousQueryResult: any, options: UpdateQueryOptions) => any) => void;
}
```

So `ChildProps` should contain both `loading` and `error` properties. I guess an error comes from `| undefined` part, but i can't get why this union even comes up.

Any suggestions?

P. S. If i do not import default `ChildProps` from `react-apollo/types`, but rather use this updated version:

```
type ChildProps<P, R> = P & {
    data: QueryProps & R;
    mutate?: MutationFunc<R>;
};
```

my code is working. What i still don't get is - did i do something wrong or is this a bug in `react-apollo/types` package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `graphql` type annotation takes `<ParentProps, QueryResponse, Variables>`.  You're passing it

```
graphql<ArticlesFeedResponse, {}>(ARTICLES_FEED)
```

when you should be passing it

```
graphql<{} ArticlesFeedResponse>(ARTICLES_FEED)
```

Secondly, as you noted, the `ChildProps` annotation states that `data` can be `undefined`.  Accounting for that, everything should typecheck.

```
class App extends React.Component<ChildProps<{}, ArticlesFeedResponse>, {}> {
  render() {
    if (!this.props.data) {
      return;
    }

    const { loading, feed, error } = this.props.data;

    if (loading) return <div>loading </div>;
    if (error) return <div>{error} </div>;

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
      <h1>It works!</h1>
        {
          feed && feed.map((article: Article) => (
            <div>{ article.shortText } </div>
          ))
        }
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

Or alternatively, mark `const { loading, feed, error } = this.props.data!;` to tell the typechecker it won't be undefined.  AFAIK, the `data` prop should never be undefined, so you're safe marking it as present with `this.props.data!`, ...and maybe the `ChildProps` annotation is incorrect/a bug?  Notably, the [example docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/recipes/static-typing.html#operation-result) don't typecheck.

Tested against `react-apollo@2.1.9`

Comment: It was a bug somewhere in apollo-graphql, which was fixed as far as i know. But thanks for the answer anyway.

Comment: I can still reproduce against `react-apollo@2.1.9`, so opened a ticket [here](https://github.com/apollographql/react-apollo/issues/2189).

Comment: As a matter of fact, i stopped using TS with `react-apollo`, as it created far more problems than solved (for me, at least), now i just use https://www.npmjs.com/package/prop-types to typecheck props on runtime and that's it.